# Disabling cookies in ad.doubleclick.net urls for GDPR compliance

Tags: javascript, cookies, ads, gdprconsentform

Our site has a relationship with a 3rd party that displays ads on our site.

The ad url comes in as `https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adi/more/unique/info` ....

We are trying to be GDPR compliant and should the user decline cookie tracking, I want to still show the ad but disable any cookies being set from doubleclick.net.

I've seen some examples of this url with params like `gdpr_consent` but setting that to `false` or `0` still results in a cookie being set.

Does anyone have any experience in disabling cookies for this ad url?

Comment: what is your main adserver ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your main adserver is Google Ad Manager (GAM) :

According to the officicial documentation GAM is not able to work without using technical cookies, even if personalized ads = false :

> Although non-personalized ads don’t use cookies or mobile ad identifiers for ad targeting, they do still use cookies or mobile ad identifiers for frequency capping, aggregated ad reporting, and to combat fraud and abuse. Therefore, you must obtain consent to use cookies or mobile ad identifiers for those purposes where legally required, per the ePrivacy Directive in certain EEA countries.

[Documentation](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9005435?hl=en&ref_topic=28145)

GAM also provide a "limited ads" library, but it still needs consent on specific purposes to work properly :

> No consent for Purpose 1 &
> Legitimate interest or consent for Purposes 2, 7, 9, and 10

See [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9882911?hl=en) for full details

To conclude, GAM does not seem to be able to work properly without cookie drops. That is why some editors use 2 adservers : GAM if cookie is allowed, a cookieless compliant adserver (xandr, smartadserver...) if not.

From my personnal experience : if cookie consent is denied, you might end up with GAM errors such as "unable to fetch ad unit". Library is loaded, but as TCF string does not grant cookie use, ad requests wont succeed.